# How to set default-encoding in undertow subsystem as utf-8 with a CLI script?

Tags: utf-8, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly, configuration-files

I'm running a WildFly10 Application Server. Now I noticed that as I changed the default encoding in the standalone.xml configuration file to utf-8, the change got erased as the server was rebooted.

Then I read up that I should use a CLI script. Now, how can I do that? What form of CLI script would add the attribute default-encoding="UTF-8" to the undertow subsystem as follows:

Here's the unmodified part of standalone.xml:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="http"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

And here it is modified, as I'd like it to be **and remain** in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

So the **only** thing changed here is the added `default-encoding="utf-8"` attribute in the `<servlet-container>` tag. How can I add it via a CLI script? Thank you.

Comment: Modifying the XML will work if the server is stopped. If it is running and configuration changes it will be overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run write-attribute operation on servlet-container resource

```
/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribute(name="default-encoding", value="utf-8")
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this out just before your answer :) It is correct. Not sure if you should add a comma between the name and value? I did.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work for me without the comma between name and value. This correct command should be:
`/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribute(name="default-encoding", value="utf-8")`